# No results when setting the firstpage header

Tags: ms-word, office-js

When you look at the documentation for office-js api's you have three header locations:

- primary
- firstpage
- even

I would expect that setting a firstpage header would only show on the first page. However I doesn't seem to do anything. Am I missing something? The documentation is not very clear on this. In this sample only the primary is showing up.

```
private setHeader(): void {
Word.run((context) => {
    let body = context.document.body;
    let sections = context.document.sections;
    context.load(sections, 'body/style');

    return context.sync()
        .then(() => {
            let primary = sections.items[0].getHeader(Word.HeaderFooterType.primary);
            primary.insertText('primary', Word.InsertLocation.replace)
            let firstPage = sections.items[0].getHeader(Word.HeaderFooterType.firstPage);
            firstPage.insertText('first page', Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            context.sync()
                .then(() => { },
                ((result: OfficeErrorMessage) => {
                    this.setErrorState(result);
                })
            );
            ;
        });
});
}
```

ps. the sample is typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very good question. if you set the headers with the API and then select the 'Different First Page' option on the Design ribbon of the header[image: Ribbon sample]

you will see that effectively the header is there. The bad part is that we are fixing a bug to make sure its shown, basically we will expose those properties in the section object, we are planning to ship those as part of the next deliverable of the Word js API.  Now, those options are actually on the file format (the odd and events on the settings package as `<w:evenAndOddHeaders/>`  , and the 'Different first' a `<w:titlePg>`  element is added on the section definition, so maybe inserting an OOXML can be a workaround for now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I followed this guide: http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml?product=word (which is quite good) and created an ooxml snippet that only has a simple header. When I try to set it with the addin i can't seem to get it to work. Is there a sample somewhere that shows this is working?

Comment: I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248569/open-xml-headers-not-being-set-with-office-addin