# Open xml headers not being set with Office Addin

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-js

I'm going through this, pretty good, document (http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/create-better-add-ins-for-word-with-office-open-xml?product=word) to understand OOXML better and to use it in a Word Addin.

To test my created OOXM, I use this sample: http://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5789.

Simple stuff works, but when I try to set the headers of the document it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the OOXML snippet:

```
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
<pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512">
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
            <Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/>
        </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256">
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
            <Relationship Id="rId7" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header2.xml"/>
            <Relationship Id="rId6" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/header" Target="header1.xml"/>
        </Relationships>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14">
            <w:body>
                <w:p w:rsidR="003F424D" w:rsidRDefault="003F424D">
                    <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
                    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:br w:type="page"/>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00C24E89" w:rsidRDefault="009F0685"/>
                <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00C24E89" w:rsidSect="003F424D">
                    <w:headerReference w:type="default" r:id="rId6"/>
                    <w:headerReference w:type="first" r:id="rId7"/>
                    <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
                    <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
                    <w:cols w:space="708"/>
                    <w:titlePg/>
                    <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
                </w:sectPr>
            </w:body>
        </w:document>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <w:endnotes xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14">
            <w:endnote w:type="separator" w:id="-1">
                <w:p w:rsidR="009F0685" w:rsidRDefault="009F0685" w:rsidP="003F424D">
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:separator/>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:endnote>
            <w:endnote w:type="continuationSeparator" w:id="0">
                <w:p w:rsidR="009F0685" w:rsidRDefault="009F0685" w:rsidP="003F424D">
                    <w:pPr>
                        <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                    </w:pPr>
                    <w:r>
                        <w:continuationSeparator/>
                    </w:r>
                </w:p>
            </w:endnote>
        </w:endnotes>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/header1.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <w:hdr xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14">
            <w:p w:rsidR="003F424D" w:rsidRPr="003F424D" w:rsidRDefault="003F424D">
                <w:pPr>
                    <w:pStyle w:val="Koptekst"/>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:lang w:val="nl-NL"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                </w:pPr>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:lang w:val="nl-NL"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>OtherPagesHeader</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:hdr>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
<pkg:part pkg:name="/word/header2.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.header+xml">
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <w:hdr xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14">
            <w:p w:rsidR="003F424D" w:rsidRPr="003F424D" w:rsidRDefault="003F424D">
                <w:pPr>
                    <w:pStyle w:val="Koptekst"/>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:lang w:val="nl-NL"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                </w:pPr>
                <w:r>
                    <w:rPr>
                        <w:lang w:val="nl-NL"/>
                    </w:rPr>
                    <w:t>FirstPageHeader</w:t>
                </w:r>
            </w:p>
        </w:hdr>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
    <pkg:xmlData>
        <w:fonts xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se">
            <w:font w:name="Calibri">
                <w:panose1 w:val="020F0502020204030204"/>
                <w:charset w:val="00"/>
                <w:family w:val="swiss"/>
                <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
                <w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C000247B" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
            </w:font>
            <w:font w:name="Times New Roman">
                <w:panose1 w:val="02020603050405020304"/>
                <w:charset w:val="00"/>
                <w:family w:val="roman"/>
                <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
                <w:sig w:usb0="E0002EFF" w:usb1="C000785B" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
            </w:font>
            <w:font w:name="Calibri Light">
                <w:panose1 w:val="020F0302020204030204"/>
                <w:charset w:val="00"/>
                <w:family w:val="swiss"/>
                <w:pitch w:val="variable"/>
                <w:sig w:usb0="E0002AFF" w:usb1="C000247B" w:usb2="00000009" w:usb3="00000000" w:csb0="000001FF" w:csb1="00000000"/>
            </w:font>
        </w:fonts>
    </pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
```

I'm a bit confused on what I'm missing here to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon further investigation, you cannot modify the header visibility with OOXML. the good news is that we are going to include a few properties at the section level to enable showing primary and even-page headers.

Comment: Ok, didn't expect this. Any ideas on when the next release will be and if these properties will be included?

Comment: we will ship a preview of the API around mid November. will update this answer when ready. thanks.