# How to insert header for "FirstPage" of a Word document office.js api?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I use Word API to insert header into a document in Word 2016 (desktop version). Insert only works for primary header. The code runs without error for `getHeader("firstPage")` and `getHeader("evenPages")` but no result.
What can be wrong?

```
// Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
Word.run(function (context) {

    // Create a proxy sectionsCollection object.
    var mySections = context.document.sections;

    // Queue a commmand to load the sections.
    context.load(mySections, 'body/style');

    // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
    // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
    return context.sync().then(function () {

        // Create a proxy object the primary header of the first section. 
        // Note that the header is a body object.
        //var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary");
        var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("firstpage");
        //var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("evenpages");

        // Queue a command to insert text at the end of the header.
        myHeader.insertText("This is a header.", Word.InsertLocation.end);

        // Queue a command to wrap the header in a content control.
        myHeader.insertContentControl();

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, 
        // and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            console.log("Added a header to the first section.");
        });                    
    });  
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

When I try case with code line

```
var myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader("firstpage");
```

And I expect to get the Header on the first page only.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "no result". Is the `myHeader` variable null or undefined?

Comment: This was asked a couple of years ago, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164991/no-results-when-setting-the-firstpage-header/39175772#39175772 AND https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248569/open-xml-headers-not-being-set-with-office-addin. In the latter, Juan Balmori mentions the capability will be added, but never updated that thread. I *think* the behavior hasn't changed, though and, if the option (first link) hasn't been activated by the user or the COM object model the non-primary headers/footers aren't available to the JS APIs...